# How to hook into WndProc using Python clr WinForms

Tags: python, winforms, clr, wndproc

My end goal is to have a resizable, borderless window using [pywebview](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview).  I'm using Windows and WinForms.
I'm able to make it borderless by doing this:

```
webview.winforms.BrowserView.instance.browser.FormBorderStyle = 0
```

However, I'd like to be able to move it around and resize it too.  To do this normally in C#, I can override the `WndProc` method in the derived Form class and call the resize messages.  I'm not sure how to do this in Python though.  The Form in pywebview is [defined here](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/blob/master/webview/winforms.py#L34).

I'm not able to set `self.WndProc` to my own definition; I get `AttributeError : attribute is read-only`.  I tried hooking directly into it like this (in the form definition):

```
WndProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_long, c_int, c_int, c_int)
GWL_WNDPROC = -4
handle = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(None)
self.oldWndProc = self.WndProc
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(handle, GWL_WNDPROC, WndProcType(self.MyWndProc))
def MyWndProc(self, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam):
    print ("is it working?")
    return CallWindowProc(
        self.oldWndProc,
        hWnd,
        msg,
        wParam,
        lParam
    )
```

But it doesn't seem to get called.

Answer (score 0):

`GetModuleHandle` retrieves an application module handle, not a window handle.
You a need handle returned from `CreateWindow`/`GetActiveWindow` or another function which returns the handle of the window!

Try this:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(self.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, WndProcType(self.MyWndProc))
```